# Element is not Visible error even if my xpath is unique

Tags: xpath, selenium-webdriver, element, invisible

Element is not Visible error even if my xpath is unique

```
//System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");

//WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
//WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.goindigo.in/");

driver.findElement(By.linkText("One Way")).click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonGlbl btn-close button-trigger']")).click();
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='innertab-content one-way-tab-ctnt']//li[@class='city-dropdown destination-dropdown ps-destination-dropdown without_label']//div[@class='city-dropdown-list city-name-to']//ul//li[3]")).click();
}
}//
```

Comment: Yes, you can get ElementNotVisible error even if you use unique selector... So what is your question?

Comment: I am unable to select the city from the drop-down. I am not sure how to proceed

Answer (score 0):

```
/System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://chromedriver.exe");

//WebDriver driver= new FirefoxDriver();
//WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();

driver.manage().window().maximize();
driver.get("https://www.goindigo.in/");

WebElement onewayLink=driver.findElement(By.linkText("One Way"));
onewayLink.click();
WebElement btnElement=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='btn buttonGlbl btn-close button-trigger']"));

WebDriverWait wait= new WebDriverWait(driver,20 );
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(btnElement));
btnElement.click();
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='innertab-content one-way-tab-ctnt']//li[@class='city-dropdown destination-dropdown ps-destination-dropdown without_label']//div[@class='city-dropdown-list city-name-to']//ul//li[3]")).click();
}
}//
```

Comment: I tried this now, but same error. I am able to click on ok button but after that I am unable to select the city from first dropdown.

Comment: Ok let me try again

Comment: if it is drip down u have to select it

Comment: It is selection indore as city the code is written, what u waqnted to select

Comment: Are you able to run it ? Its just I want to select any city.

Comment: it is not drop down, it is JS, Yes i get Indore as city

Answer (score 0):

Above answer, no one hit the root cause, it has nothing to do with need to wait some element.

The root cause is you need to click on the input box of From/To city to make the city list pop-up, then click on the city you wanted.

This is a selenium design principle: an element must be visible, before selenium to click it.

The selenium desinger hope it can simulator operations from user perspective, as we know user need to see the city list before he can choose one. So we also need to make selenium 'see' the city list at first.

But one exception, when you want to select an option from a Select, you can 
directly click on the option your wanted, no need to make the options pop-up firstly.

you can find such question from below link, and I give out the detail answer for it.
[Using firefox webdriver trying to load the option Name from dropdown but not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46133643/using-firefox-webdriver-trying-to-load-the-option-name-from-dropdown-but-not-wor)

Code snippet to fix your issue:

```
driver.get("https://www.goindigo.in/"); 
// click 'One Way' tab
driver.findElement(By.css(".one-way-tab")).click();
// Click 'OK' on Information pop-up
driver.findElement(By.css(".buttonGlbl.btn-close")).click();

// Click 'From' city input box for 'One Way'
driver.findElement(By.css("#oneWay .origins-value.city-name-value")).click();
// Choose city 'Delhi'
driver.findElement(By.css("#oneWay .origin-city-name"))
      .findElement(By.partialLinkText("Delhi"))
      .click();

// Click 'To' city input box for 'One Way'
driver.findElement(By.css("#oneWay .destinations-value.city-name-value")).click();
// Choose city 'Indore'
driver.findElement(By.css("#oneWay .dest-city-name"))
      .findElement(By.partialLinkText("Indore"))
      .click();
```

Comment: Hey, Thanks I am able to run it by your code. But somehow when scripts runs it automatically selecting Delhi in from list so it got failed initially but I changed to other city and it worked. I will see why it is selecting Delhi automatically.