# Using firefox webdriver trying to load the option Name from dropdown but not working?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

below i am not able to load the list of mobiles using Name order, using code it is selecting the option from drop-down NAME but the instantly loads the previous page only. when i run the below code it is selecting the Name tag but result is not showing on the output screen.

```
package selflearning;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;

public class Guru99Ecommerce1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\geckodriver\\geckodriver.exe"); 
        WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/index.php/");

        String title=driver.getTitle();
        String expectedTitle="Home page";
        System.out.println("The title of the webPage is "+title);
        expectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title);
        System.out.println("Title is verified");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Mobile']")).click();

        String nextTitle=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("The title of next page"+nextTitle);

        String nextExpectedTitle="pageMobile";
        nextExpectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(nextTitle);
        System.out.println("The next title is verified");


        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']//div/div[@class='sorter']/div/select[@title='Sort By']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='category-products']//div/div[@class='sorter']/div/select/option[2]")).click();


        Thread.sleep(5000);




    }

}
```

Comment: Waht exactly u wanted

Comment: open that URL mentioned above, then go to the mobile section, by default they are sorted in position order, i wanted to display them in Name order

Comment: try this it is working

Comment: select class it works man, i was tryinf to find the xpath of Name tag and then click on it , some how it was not working.

Comment: but need to ask one thing, after sorting by Name tag, lets say if i want to check if displayed Items are in ascending order only how could i achieve that

Comment: After loading name sorting, You have o select the ascending order sorting

Comment: List<WebElement> element=driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='product-info']/h2/a"));
        
        for(WebElement e: element)
        {
         String str=e.getText();
         System.out.println("The items are"+str);
         
        }

Comment: sankalp help here , how to check now if above elements are in order, how to change the above List into arraylist or any other trick ?

Comment: Let me try and give possible soultion if ic an

Comment: please, it will help a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this code, You miss the `Select` class to select drop down

```
   driver.get("http://live.guru99.com/index.php/");

        String title=driver.getTitle();
        String expectedTitle="Home page";
        System.out.println("The title of the webPage is "+title);
        expectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(title);
        System.out.println("Title is verified");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()='Mobile']")).click();

        String nextTitle=driver.getTitle();
        System.out.println("The title of next page"+nextTitle);

        String nextExpectedTitle="pageMobile";
        nextExpectedTitle.equalsIgnoreCase(nextTitle);
        System.out.println("The next title is verified");

        Select s=new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='top']/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/div[1]/div/select")));
        s.selectByVisibleText("Name");
```

Comment: Is my code works for u @gaurav. If yes Please upvote and Accept as asnwer

Answer (score 0):

Actually for HTML Select tag,  we can directly click on the option your want, no need to click the select to expand the option list firstly then click option.

So you can try below code:

```
public void chooseOrderBy(String orderBy) {

driver
.findElement(by.css("[title='Sort By']"))
.findElement(by.xpath(String.format("./option[contains(text(), '%s')]", orderBy))
.click();

}
```

From user experience, user need to see all options before he can choose the one he wanted, so user have to click on the select to make it pop-up all options firstly.

But automation no need to see all options before it can choose one option. it can directly click the option to complete choose.

Running above code, you will noticed the select not pop-up options before chose option during autoamtion running.

Of course click select to pop-up options, then choose option, this should also work.  But one more time to operate on page.

Reminder:  directly click on option only support dropdown list by HTML Select tag, for those Jquery drop down list, you have to click to pop-up options, then choose one from them.